# IBM API Connect API Designer not starting

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, apiconnect

I created a API Connect project with command

```
apic loopback
```

When I try to launch the API designer, I receive error as below:

```
sdil@sdil-VirtualBox:~/Project/test-apic/todo4$ apic edit

The user model "User" is attached to an application that does not specify
whether other sessions should be invalidated when a password or
an email has changed. Session invalidation is important for security
reasons as it allows users to recover from various account breach
situations.

We recommend turning this feature on by setting
"logoutSessionsOnSensitiveChanges" to true in
server/config.json (unless you have implemented your own solution
for token invalidation).

We also recommend enabling "injectOptionsFromRemoteContext" in
User's settings (typically via common/models/*.json file).
This setting is required for the invalidation algorithm to keep
the current session valid.

Learn more in our documentation at
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/AccessToken-invalidation.html

Error: loopback.errorHandler is no longer available. Please use the module "strong-error-handler" instead.
```

When I check for declaration in package.json, I did see strong-error-handler written.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.0.0",
}
```

How do i fix this to make API Designer running?

Comment: Have you actually installed the module? npm install :)

Comment: @Undrium

I ran "npm ls" in the folder and i see it is installed:

└─┬ strong-error-handler@2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I sort of recognize this problem, actually. We had the new strong-error-handler but also the old one active.

Do the steps in "Migration from old LoopBack error handler" here:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-strong-error-handler.html#migration-from-old-loopback-error-handler

Should eliminate the old one completely.

Comment: @sdil: Does this answer help solve your issue? If so can you please mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Undrium I generated the project scaffold using command apic loopback with loopback version 3.x. It has done all the steps given in the documentation. However, it's still not working. I do not even have loopback.errorHandler package in my npm list